# Copyright violations in creating original trivia questions based on popular books, videos and articles

Tags: copyright

If I compose an online trivia quiz for general users, and create questions such as

- Q1) To which Hogwarts House did Harry Potter belong ? (based on a Harry Potter book)
- Q2) Does a honey badger attack a lion ? (based on a specific National Geographic video)
- Q3) Who said this in 2002 "..." ? (based on an article in say, TIME magazine)

Is this a violation of any copyright law ? Am I expected to take explicit permissions etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 are definitely not copyright violations. Copyright protects original expression. Your questions are yours; the only things you are using are the names, and copyright doesn't cover them on their own.

The quotation in Q3 *might* conceivably come under copyright. However in practice it is very likely to be fair use (unfortunately nothing is definitely fair use until a court rules on it, but I can't imagine a short quotation in a quiz being an issue).